# Test that child components props are constructed properly when prop is a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

Im trying to test that the props on my child element are being set properly. So I have this component :

```
export default class Select extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FormGroup className="col-md-3">
                <FormControl
                    componentClass="select"
                    name={this.props.name}
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onChange={(event) => this.props.onChange(event, this.props.index)}
                >
                    {this.getOptionElements()}
                </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
        )
    }
```

And im trying to test the onchange function is being set properly.

```
it('should pass props to FormControl', () => {
    let props = {
        'options': [],
        'name': 'name',
        'value': "value",
        'index': '1',
        'onChange': () => {}
    };
    const expectedOnChange = (event) => this.props.onChange(event, this.props.index);
    const wrapper = mount(<Select {...props}/>);
    const formControlProps = wrapper.find('FormControl').props();

    expect(formControlProps.componentClass).to.equal('select');
    expect(formControlProps.name).to.equal(props.name);
    expect(formControlProps.value).to.equal(props.value);
    expect(formControlProps.onChange).to.equal(expectedOnChange);
});
```

I know this isnt working because the functions arent the same reference. Is there a way to test that the function is being constructed properly? I tried to mimic how the onChange is being constructed in the test but its still not the same reference. Im really curious is this is even possible or what the best approach to test this would be?

---------------EDIT--------------------------

My updated Test

```
it('should set onChange on FormControl and pass in event and index', () => {
    const onChangeStub = sinon.stub();
    const eventStub = sinon.stub();
    let props = {
        'options': [],
        'index': '1',
        'onChange': onChangeStub
    };
    const expectedOnChange = (event) => this.props.onChange(event, this.props.index);
    const wrapper = mount(<Select {...props}/>);
    const formControl = wrapper.find('FormControl');

    formControl.simulate('change', eventStub);

    onChangeStub.should.have.been.calledOnce;
    onChangeStub.should.have.been.calledWith(eventStub, props.index)
});
```

This issue now is my assert. CalledWith is failing because the event is being passed in as well so the args are (event, index). How do I assert that the event is called? Im getting a failing assertion here

Comment: Why not declare a function and then pass it both as a prop to the component and as an argument to `expect(•).to.equal(•)`?

Answer (score 1):

the function that `FormControl` calls when the `onChange` event happens is part of the `props` for `Select`. The way to test this I think would be to pass a mock for that in the test when initializing `Select`, and triggering an `onChange` event for the component. The number of calls for the mock should be one.

The way your current test is constructed, it seems that you are testing that an arrow function binds `this` correctly. If that is the case, the test does not really refers to your own code, but to the actual implementation of ES, which I don't think you should cover in your own tests.

Comment: well the code seems correct to me. What is the error that you are getting?